# I'm larger than life, and I eat everything that is provided to me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Undoubtedly, I have a big stomach, it's just in my nature.
> Nothing can escape me, my thirst atomic, considered a danger.
>
> I'm bigger than most everything, does that mean I am fat?
> Vain men may use me like a sling, can I be used like that?
>
> Ever consuming, my insides unreachable.
> Release fuming, is how I'm born feasible?
>
> So very dark, I seek for stability.
> Effect my spark, you'll need volatility.

What am I?

<sub>Effect is intentional</sub>

Comment: this is way too easy. you should remove the word atomic because it instantly makes you think science related and in that setting the answer is trivial from the clues.

Comment: One of the Backstreet Boys with an eating disorder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> black hole

Undoubtedly, I have a big stomach, it's just in my nature.

> They can "eat" things

Nothing can escape me, my thirst atomic, considered a danger.

> There is so much force that nothing, not even light can escape.

I'm bigger than most everything, does that mean I am fat?

> The one in the center on the Milky Way is bigger than the sun I think?

Vain men may use me like a sling, can I be used like that?

> El-Guest said that people with spaceships may want to use black holes as a source of energy.

Ever consuming, my insides unreachable.

> They are large.

Release fuming, is how I'm born feasible

> Maybe it releases waves?

So very dark, I seek for stability.

> Black hole = dark hole

Effect my spark, you'll need volatility.

> It means to use the gravity from the black hole to slingshot yourself to another place.

Also

> The first letter of each line spells UNIVERSE

Title

> Black holes are enormous and they do eat everything in their gravitational pull.

Comment: This is it, nice job.

Comment: Ya got me! Great answer. (+1 back at you!) :D

Comment: QuantumTwinkie, for the sling, [this page is what I first thought of](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/530/could-black-holes-be-used-for-swing-by); it's an extension of a [more common (and less interesting) maneuver currently used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist).

Answer (score 11):

Are you a

> black hole?

Undoubtedly, I have a big stomach, it's just in my nature.

> They try to eat everything

Nothing can escape me, my thirst atomic, considered a danger.

> Nothing can escape from a black hole

I'm bigger than most everything, does that mean I am fat?

> They're centres of most galaxies

Vain men may use me like a sling, can I be used like that?

> It's been proposed that [spaceships can use black holes as sources of energy similar to a slingshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/530/could-black-holes-be-used-for-swing-by)

Ever consuming, my insides unreachable.

> You get spaghettified long before then

Release fuming, is how I'm born feasible?

> Born by a collapsing star (hopefully not nearby!)

So very dark, I seek for stability.

> The black in black hole; they stabilize galaxies

Effect my spark, you'll need volatility.

> This could refer to quantum gravity effects on black holes?

Bonus:

> UNIVERSE is spelled out in the acrostic

Comment: You got it, good job. QuantumTwinkie beat you to it, but your answers are better.

Comment: Ahh I'm slow on the draw today, great puzzle @Joe-You-Know! Was my explanation what you meant by "effect my spark"?

Comment: Actually, I was referring to a rot13(Fhcreabin rkcybqvat naq gura pbyyncfvat), but this is fine.

Comment: Ohhh that makes more sense, thanks very much!